# PMP certification without having served in a management position

Tags: product-management, pmp, certification

I am looking to get certified in project management , however in my 20 year job history I have never held a "Manager" title.  I have served in an "software developer" , "system analyst" and "application architect" role , but never a "manager" . Is this a show stopper for PMP ?  Per PMP requirement one has to have previous project management experience to qualify.

I have led projects ( more of a scrum master role) before.  How do I know if this qualifies for PMP certification?

thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be asked to PMP, not strangers on the internet.

Comment: Having project management experience is a prerequisite for PMP certification and it is a subject to interpretation . I don't understand your comment " should be asked to PMP and not strangers on the internet" .. isn't what this forum  designed to do , asking strangers topic relevant questions?

Comment: In this case, though, any answers you receive here are meaningless. If we say 'yes' and PMP says 'no', then the answer is clearly 'no'. You should just ask PMP instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does not matter:
- Your job title;
- Whether you managed a project end-to-end;

What does matter:
- You had a leading/directing role;
- You have experience with all five main process groups (being Initiating, Planning, Executing, Monitoring & Controlling and Closing).

Please find more explanation in the PMP Handbook on the PMI site.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the PMP criteria on PMI's website.  The criterion you seem to be struggling with is the experience one, in which PMI requires either 7,500 or 4,500 of hours (depending on your college degree situation) "leading and directing" projects.  That criterion does not use the word "manage" or any of its derivatives nor do any of the criteria require a "management" title of any sort.  None of the criteria speaks to any title whatsoever.  So based on the published criteria, a lack of management title should not filter you out.  But as Sarov suggested above, you should not rely on us or this site to indicate whether your application would be accepted.

Comment: Unfortunately neither PMP support or training centers would provide a meaningful definition for  this criteria.

Answer (score 1):

It is sometimes misleading to have a "manager" title without having real-life experience in project management. Even if it is not stated in your title, if you can show and materialize your past experience in either one of the five main process groups, then PMI will not worry about the lack of a "manager" title.

You're good to go. All the best.